# pytorch landmark detection model--Problem defining the outputs

Tags: python, pytorch

I am new to machine learning and Python, but I'm trying to set up a model to detect landmarks on projectile points (arrowheads). The problem I have appears to be that the model returns 392 pairs of landmarks instead of 8 pairs of x,y landmarks.

This is the specific part of the code where my model is defined:

```
class LandmarkDetector(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_landmarks=8):
        super(LandmarkDetector, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.pool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.pool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(64*8*8, 512)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512, num_landmarks*2)

    def forward(self, x):
        # Convolutional layers
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = nn.functional.relu(x)
        x = self.pool1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = nn.functional.relu(x)
        x = self.pool2(x)
        # Flatten
        x = x.view(-1, 64*8*8)

        # Fully connected layers
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = nn.functional.relu(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)

        # Reshape to landmark coordinates
        x = x.view(-1, 8, 2)
        print(x[0].shape)

        return x
```

Any tips would be appreciated.

Here is the full code:

```
import os
os.chdir('C:/Users/rjbischo/Dropbox (ASU)/Projects/Dissertation')

import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
import torch
import torchvision.transforms as transforms

class LandmarkDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, csv_file, root_dir, transform=None):
        """
        Args:
            csv_file (string): Path to the CSV file with annotations.
            root_dir (string): Directory with all the images.
            transform (callable, optional): Optional transform to be applied
                on a sample.
        """
        self.landmarks = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.landmarks)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        img_name = self.landmarks.iloc[idx, 0]
        img_path = os.path.join(self.root_dir, img_name)
        image = Image.open(img_path).convert('L')  # Load the image as grayscale
        landmarks = self.landmarks.iloc[idx, 1:].values.astype('float32')
        landmarks = torch.from_numpy(landmarks)
        landmarks = landmarks.view(-1, 2)
        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)
        return image, landmarks


# Define transforms for training and validation datasets
data_transforms = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.5], std=[0.5])  # Update normalization for grayscale images
])


import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torchvision.models as models
from torchvision import transforms
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
# torch.set_default_tensor_type(torch.FloatTensor)

class LandmarkDetector(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_landmarks=8):
        super(LandmarkDetector, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.pool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.pool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(64*8*8, 512)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512, num_landmarks*2)

    def forward(self, x):
        # Convolutional layers
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = nn.functional.relu(x)
        x = self.pool1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = nn.functional.relu(x)
        x = self.pool2(x)
        # Flatten
        x = x.view(-1, 64*8*8)

        # Fully connected layers
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = nn.functional.relu(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)

        # Reshape to landmark coordinates
        x = x.view(-1, 8, 2)
        print(x[0].shape)

        return x

# Define the training parameters
batch_size = 8
lr = 0.001
num_epochs = 3

# Load the training and validation data
train_dataset = LandmarkDataset("data/landmarksSideTrain.csv",".", transform=data_transforms)
val_dataset = LandmarkDataset("data/landmarksSideValidate.csv",".", transform=data_transforms)
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=batch_size)

# Initialize the model, loss function, and optimizer
model = LandmarkDetector()
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr)

# Train the model
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    train_loss = 0.0
    val_loss = 0.0
    model.train()
    for images, labels in train_loader:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(images)
        print(len(outputs))
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        train_loss += loss.item() * images.size(0)
    train_loss /= len(train_dataset)
    model.eval()
    with torch.no_grad():
        for images, labels in val_loader:
            images = images
            labels = labels
            outputs = model(images)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            val_loss += loss.item() * images.size(0)
        val_loss /= len(val_dataset)
    print(f'Epoch {epoch+1}: train_loss={train_loss:.4f}, val_loss={val_loss:.4f}')
```

Error: RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (392) must match the size of tensor b (8) at non-singleton dimension 0